# Map is not defined on array

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to iterate and map over this array and pull data from it. When trying to run the code, I get an error saying "data.data.children.map(...).then is not a function", even though data.data.children is an array. Thanks.

```js
var output
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/somesubreddit/hot/.json?count=20')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    //console.log(data.data.children)
    data.data.children.map(hit => output = {
      score: hit.score,
      title: hit.title,
      permalink: hit.permalink
    }).then(result => {
      var done = result.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.score - a.score
      })
      this.setState({
        hits: done
      })
    })
  }).catch(err => console.log(err.message)); // To illustrate your error
```

Comment: you have a syntax error. you forgot the `=` sign on line one

Comment: correct, `.map` returns an **Array** - array's do **not** have a `.then` method

Comment: The function `map` from `Array.prototype` returns an Array.

Comment: note: your question title is misleading ... because it's `.then` that isn't defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` doesn't return a `Promise`. You can't use `.then()` to chain its output.

`.map()` should be synchronous, so there's no need to use `.then()`. Just immediately use its output like so:

```
var output
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/somesubreddit/hot/.json?count=20')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.data.children)
        var result = data.data.children.map(hit => output = {
            score: hit.score,
            title: hit.title,
            permalink: hit.permalink
        });

        var done = result.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b.score - a.score
        })
        this.setState({
            hits: done
        })
    });
```

You can simplify this further by chaining the outputs of `map` and `sort` to remove the intermediate variable:

```
var output
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/somesubreddit/hot/.json?count=20')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.data.children)
        var result = data.data.children.map(hit => {
            score: hit.score,
            title: hit.title,
            permalink: hit.permalink
        }).sort(function(a, b) {
            return b.score - a.score
        });

        this.setState({
            hits: result
        })
    });
```

Keep in mind that you're only using the `.then()` calls on the `fetch()` call, since the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is based on promises. Any implementation outside the fetch or within its callbacks do not implicitly use Promises by default, so you can't use `.then()` on them.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors

1. map returns an array, which has no `.then` method
2. this `output = {` ... no need for `output` variable
3. the data isn't in the format you think it is

```js
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/somesubreddit/hot/.json?count=20')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => data.data.children.map(({data:{score, title, permalink}}) => ({score, title, permalink})))
    .then(result => {
        var done = result.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b.score - a.score
        });
        /*
        this.setState({
            hits: done
        });
        */
        console.log(done);
    })
```

Note: the above can also be written

```
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/r/somesubreddit/hot/.json?count=20')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    var done = data.data.children.map(({data:{score, title, permalink}}) => ({score, title, permalink}))
    .sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.score - a.score
    });
    /*
    this.setState({
        hits: done
    });
    */
    console.log(done);
})
```

As there's no need for the `.map` to be done in a separate `.then` as it is synchronous